# Uniform way of passing an array in querystring in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, query-string, model-binding

I have a controller's action:

```
public ActionResult Find(IEnumerable<string> ids) { ... }
```

I'm succesfully invoking it by route `../Find?ids=01&ids=02&ids=03`. `DefaultModelBinder` easily binds the parameter with no extra configuration.
However, when I'm trying to do *outbound* routing, i.e. use code like this in my View

```
@Url.Action("Find", "Grid", new {ids=new List<string>{01,02,03}})
```

.. I'm getting a nice `..?ids=System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]` querystring in my URL. I've already found some answers which suggest writing an custom binding/routing, but I believe such a simple task should be solved much easier without any extra code.

**P.S.:** I'd be perfectly happy to change my querystring format, I just want to rely on some *default* framework behavior to accomplish the task: pass an array in querystring.

---

Short version: what is the most simple way to render a link to a controller's action with an array in querystring?

Answer (score 5):

its not elegant way... but simple and fast. Try

```
@Url.Action("Find", "Grid", new {ids= string.Join("&ids=", YourList)})
```

Comment: thanks, but it's exactly the kind of code I'm trying to avoid :) it always seems veery weird to me when you have to use hacks like this for something I'd call a "basic typical task".